# Is there an API to read file content?

Tags: files, 10

Most references seem to read files using PHP functions like `file_get_contents()`, `fgets()`, `fread()`, or `readfile()`.

Is there is any Drupal API that allows to read uploaded files independent of underlying storage?

We are using AWS S3 as our file field storage. Our ec2 instance is in a private subnet with an interface to S3 services. Say the URI is s3://bucketname/object.csv. I need a Drupal API that does an s3 getObject() SDK call under the hood that way I don't get blocked on network level instead request goes through the S3 network interface.

Comment: Please tag the question with the major Drupal version, like 7 or 10.

Comment: Sorry. This is for Drupal 10.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal implements access to managed files through stream wrappers.
So you can access files using native PHP functions as follows.

```php
file_get_contents('public://some/public/file.txt');
file_get_contents('private://some/private/file.txt');
file_get_contents('temporary://some/temporary/file.txt');
```

Comment: Thanks. There is a nuance here. We are using AWS S3 as our file field storage. Our ec2 instance is in a private subnet with an interface to S3 services. Say the URI is s3://bucketname/object.csv. I need a Drupal API that does an s3 getObject() SDK call under the hood that way I don't get blocked instead request goes through the S3 network interface.

Comment: The S3 module defines a stream wrapper for `s3://`. Whether that does what you specifically want under the hood you'd have to check, but I think that's the only existing implementation out in the wild that's been battle-tested

Comment: @Clive, sure. I will try and let you know.